# PhoneGap 3.0 with Android studio 0.2

Tags: android, workflow, android-studio

I had question on how to use Android Studio to develop PhoneGap 3.0 mobile application. We all know that Android Studio is used to write native mobile application for android, however, it also supposes to develop PhoneGap app.

> PhoneGap is a free and open source framework that allows you to create
>   mobile apps using standardized web APIs for the
>   platforms you care about.

So basically I need to write HTML, CSS and JavaScript for PhoneGap app then phonegap-cli build tool **compile** the JavaScript to some *native* code in order to run on android or ios devices. For example if I run `phonegap local build android`, then a new directory will be created under platform and all android relevant files were generated. But I don't suppose to edit or change any files under platform directory, right?

So how can I suppose to use Android Studio to develop PhoneGap application? Or how shall I suppose to elaborate Android Studio in my development workflow?

I read this [article](http://www.tricedesigns.com/2013/05/16/phonegap-android-studio/) by Andrew Trice but with no luck on my Android Studio 0.2 and phonegap 3.0.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

The article by Andrew Trice suggests to edit "www" files under

```
project-root/platforms/android/assets/www
```

but this is not correct, because if you want to develop for multiple platform, you must edit "www" files under

```
project-root/www
```

If you want to open a Phonegap project using Android Studio, you can initially follow all the steps suggested by Andrew, **then** add to the Studio project the *project-root/www* folder that the import procedure did not found:

1. List item
2. open menu File / Project Structure
3. in the left column select Modules
4. press Add Content Root and select the folder *project-root/www*
5. in the rightmost part of the window, select the new folder and press Sources
6. press OK and you will see the correct www folder in the project structure.

**BUT** there is a limitation: Android Studio doesn't support javascript and CSS editing, so you can edit these kind of files as simple text files **:-(**

Answer (score -1):

I was also struggling with Phonegap app using android studio but all in vein. Then I tried myself with different approaches and finally made my first phonegap app with android studio.
I have written one blog post with all the screen shots and details. You can go through below link.

http://code-aspdotnet.blogspot.com/

Comment: Please post your answer here, don't just paste a link to an external content. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer